# GCD of two numbers in MIPS- recursive

Tags: recursion, mips32

I am trying to find the GCD of two numbers with recursion.
This code is what I've done so far but apparently it gets into an infinite loop and i can't understand why and how to solve this problem.
I would appreciate some help

```
.data
string1: .asciiz "Enter the first number:  "
string2: .asciiz "Enter the second number:  "
string3: .asciiz "GCD is : "

.text

li $v0,4
la $a0,string1
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
add $s0,$v0,$zero  #s0 = first number

li $v0,4
la $a0,string2
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
add $s1,$v0,$zero   #s1= second number




slt $t0,$s0,$s1
beq $t0,$zero,L    # if first number < second number , swap
add $t1,$s0,$zero
add $s0,$s1,$zero
add $s1,$t1,$zero

L: 
add $a0,$s0,$zero   # put first number in $a0 as input argument
add $a1,$s1,$zero   # put second number in $a1 as input argument



jal GCD

GCD:

addi $sp,$sp,-4
sw $ra,0($sp)


bne $a1,$zero,L1  # base case condition

add $v0,$zero,$a0  # if base case is true
addi $sp,$sp,4
jr $ra


L1:
div $a0,$a1
add $a0,$a1,$zero
mfhi $a1
jal GCD


lw $ra,0($sp)
addi $sp,$sp,4

jr $ra


add $s3,$v0,$zero  # put result in $s3


li $v0,4
la $a0,string3
syscall


li $v0,1
add $a0,$s3,$zero
syscall
```

Comment: Running your program in a debugger should give you some hints about where and why it gets stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your program starts execution at the beginning of the `.text` segment and continues straight onto the line `jal GCD` after the `L` label.

Next your program jumps to the `GCD` label where it executes until the `jr $ra` which makes it return to the `jal` which has as its next instruction of course `GCD`. This causes the infinite loop.

So the problem here is that you have inserted the `GCD` function in the middle of your main function. Generally speaking it is always an error to `jal` to the next line.

So you should move the definition of `GCD` elsewhere and consider what it is that you would like to run after returning from this function.

Comment: thank you very much. I also added a jump after function call and before the GCD lable and put its lable after GCD function. That worked as well.

Comment: Good. If it worked for you please accept the answer. :)